# LTspice anomaly with pico-Farad capacitors - minimum 20µs rise-time?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, high-frequency

Why is it, if a **28800pF** (28.8nF) ideal capacitor and 4Ω resistor are in series with a voltage source, that source rises linearly to exactly t=20µs?

[image: 28800pF, can see edges but timing way off]

For C=**2880pF**, I expect \$5\tau=2880\text{pF}\cdot4\Omega\cdot 5 = 57.7\text{ns}\$ but the chart barely changes:

[image: 2880pF, can no longer see edges - timing extremely off]

I tried changing most of the simulator parameters with zero effect - it's like the voltage source has an intrinsic linear ramp-up from 0-20µs.  Is there a better way to simulate these very fast transients?  Is waiting 20µs and closing a voltage-controlled switch the best answer?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRE0d.png) is what I get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, is to remove the "startup" command, so that V1 starts at full voltage. Then `Control-Right-Click` C1 and enter "IC=0" for Value2. This makes C1 start discharged (0V.)

[image: How to simulate this]

Comment: This is it. The `startup` flag adds a 10 us ramp to DC voltage sources. For initial conditions one of `ic=<...>`, `.ic`, or `uic` should be used. In this case, `uic` will override the `ic=0`, and `ic=0` can be used without `uic`, though both won't harm anything.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way to simulate these very fast transients? Is
> waiting 20µs and closing a voltage-controlled switch the best answer?

Yes, there is a better and easier way. Rather than relying on the simulation to generate a transient on startup, produce it explicitly using a pulsed voltage source.

Right-click on the voltage symbol and choose 'advanced', then select the 'Pulse' function and input the desired parameters (including Vinitial, Von, Tdelay and Trise). This simulates a circuit that is initially powered off and then turns on after a time delay.

Answer (score 2):

When using a pulse much shorter then \$\tau\$ reaches steady state and ends quickly as is the case in both examples.  Ic never reaches the max current.

If  wanted to see the exponential voltage , then choose that instead and use only a step on a much longer pulse width.